# Long Inner joins

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have a database with multiple tables and currently doing 2 inner joins between 3 of them, and it takes up to 30sec to perform, I would like to know if it is a standard behaviour or not

Let's consider 3 tables

- messages_threads(236205 rows)
- messages(1162543 rows)
- message_classifications(720407 rows)

I'm performing the following request:

```
SELECT
 mt1.id
FROM messages_threads mt1
INNER JOIN messages m1 ON m1.messages_thread_id = mt1.id
INNER JOIN message_classifications mc1 ON mc1.message_id = m1.id
WHERE mt1.account_email = 'xxx'
AND mt1.was_merged = FALSE
```

Here is the EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
Nested Loop  (cost=35.82..14558.18 rows=2229 width=4) (actual 
    time=92.300..10820.795 rows=3066 loops=1)
 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=35.39..12824.04 rows=3467 width=8) (actual time=83.061..9385.017 rows=4906 loops=1)
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on messages_threads mt1  (cost=34.96..2809.87 rows=731 width=4) (actual time=62.338..1906.602 rows=826 loops=1)
           Recheck Cond: ((account_email)::text = 'xxx'::text)
           Filter: (NOT was_merged)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 100
           Heap Blocks: exact=869
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_messages_threads_on_account_email  (cost=0.00..34.78 rows=848 width=0) (actual time=51.016..51.016 rows=940 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: ((account_email)::text = 'xxx'::text)
     ->  Index Scan using index_messages_on_messages_thread_id on messages m1  (cost=0.43..13.61 rows=9 width=8) (actual time=3.684..9.049 rows=6 loops=826)
           Index Cond: (messages_thread_id = mt1.id)
 ->  Index Only Scan using index_message_classifications_on_message_id on message_classifications mc1  (cost=0.42..0.48 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.289..0.291 rows=1 loops=4906)
     Index Cond: (message_id = m1.id)
     Heap Fetches: 14
 Planning time: 118.012 ms
 Execution time: 10821.368 ms
```

As you can see I have setup indexes on each join attributes on each table, however the query still takes 10 sec to complete

Do you think this is expected behaviour ? (The nested loops joins are taking up the most time here)

And you have some advices on how to optimize this query ?

Thanks for the help

**EDIT WITH BUFFERS**

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=40.57..16088.17 rows=2470 width=4) (actual time=55.703..9612.504 rows=3070 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=19343 read=4357 dirtied=1
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=40.15..14166.86 rows=3841 width=8) (actual time=55.653..7811.736 rows=4910 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=4701 read=2825 dirtied=1
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on messages_threads mt1  (cost=39.72..3093.04 rows=813 width=4) (actual time=55.609..86.829 rows=827 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((account_email)::text = 'xxx'::text)
               Filter: (NOT was_merged)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 100
               Heap Blocks: exact=871
               Buffers: shared hit=873 read=7 dirtied=1
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_messages_threads_on_account_email  (cost=0.00..39.52 rows=946 width=0) (actual time=55.492..55.492 rows=942 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((account_email)::text = 'xxx'::text)
                     Buffers: shared hit=4 read=5
         ->  Index Scan using index_messages_on_messages_thread_id on messages m1  (cost=0.43..13.53 rows=9 width=8) (actual time=3.324..9.337 rows=6 loops=827)
               Index Cond: (messages_thread_id = mt1.id)
               Buffers: shared hit=3828 read=2818
   ->  Index Only Scan using index_message_classifications_on_message_id on message_classifications mc1  (cost=0.42..0.48 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.362..0.365 rows=1 loops=4910)
         Index Cond: (message_id = m1.id)
         Heap Fetches: 31
         Buffers: shared hit=14642 read=1532
 Planning time: 41.614 ms
 Execution time: 9613.068 ms
(22 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you repeat the EXPLAIN but with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`?  Preferably, `set track_io_timing to on` first.

If the cache is cold so all the data has to be read from disk, and you have slow disks (HDD rather than SSD), then this is to be expected.

But, why is the cache cold?  Are you running this query right after rebooting the server?  Do you have only a very small amount of RAM on the server?  If you run the same query a second time, is it now much faster?  What if you run the same query but with a different parameter for `account_email`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my post with the Explain ANALYZE BUFFERS you requested. The cache is indeed cold for the aforementionned request because this request is to be run only once a week. If I run the query a second time then it finishes in 30ms of course thanks to cache

Comment: If you only run it once a week, then is it really a problem that it takes 9 seconds?  If this is still a problem, there are a variety of ways to reduce it, but which one to use depends on why a 9 second query once a week is posing a problem.

Comment: Well, it is simply 2 inner joins so I suppose that with proper indexing it should not take so much time to perform, I'm interested in which solutions you are referring to for educational purposes Thanks a lot